# Is there a way to store data on Windows Forms C# using the Data Grid View?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on this project on Visual Studio now, and I am basically working on this section where it will hold this time table-like structure with the user's input of choice. In this case, since I used `DataGridView` and added several columns to it to fit the needed information, I created it and put it into its own separate form. Now with the way I access my forms is through how I learned it from YouTube using those "how to design modern UI's" videos then using that same structure(main window, buttons on the side take you to the specific section you want without closing the main window itself as the form appears within the main form) Looks like this just to make this as clear as possible (example of what I am talking about):

[image]

I followed their way of switching through forms and realised that from doing this, data would not be held for too long as going back to that same form after traversing to another one would just create a new form, and delete the old form with that data that was being kept inside of it. My question is, is there a way I can keep the data without having the forms just delete and recreate themselves? Like to go off the timetable form I was talking about earlier, return to it and the values are still there?

This is the code I usually use to switch between forms (yes it works),

```
private Form currentForm = null;

private void openChildForm(Form childForm)
{
    if (currentForm != null)
    {
        currentForm.Close();
    }
    currentForm = childForm;
    childForm.TopLevel = false;
    childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    backgroundSchedule.Controls.Add(childForm);
    backgroundSchedule.Tag = childForm;
    childForm.BringToFront();
    childForm.Show();
}

//How it's called as an example:
private void txtBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openChildForm(new summonForm());
}
```

However, if somebody did seem to ask a very similar question to mine/of the same nature, then please link me to that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Filling a grid with data and switching between forms are two different things. Can you edit your question to be more specific about what you are asking? Also, I suggest you peruse the SO [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) section as it shows how SO works. The [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help. In addition, you may find the SO [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section useful.

Comment: I'm saying that because I'm switching forms I lose the data I put into the Data Grids, so is there any other way I could switch forms without losing that data?

Comment: From what I can see you are not “switching” forms. The code is “creating” a new form. You can “create" a new form then “show/hide” the form as needed without creating a new form each time.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Would I keep the code the same as it is (with few adjustments of course) then only show it instead of recreating it?

Comment: _”...only show it instead of recreating it…”_ Yes, create the form(s) “once,” then show/hide the forms as needed.